# Turbolinks with Adsense asynchronous ad code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, adsense, turbolinks

Is there a way to make new Adsense Async code work reliably with Turbolinks on in Rails 4 app?

Here's a sample adsense async code straight from [google](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666?hl=en&ref_topic=1307438):

```
<script async src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
    style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
    data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    data-ad-slot="6440411535"></ins>
<script>(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>
```

All ads load fine on full page refresh but when I randomly browse through the site they fail to load reliably (sometimes none of them loads, sometimes only one or two load).

I guess the solution will be to reload the ads on the `page:change` event somehow.

I'm also wondering if it's OK to use adsense with "ajax-based" page reloads through Turbolinks.

Answer (score 1):

This code currently works well with **Turbolinks 5**.

```
function parseAds() {
  var ads = document.querySelectorAll('.adsbygoogle');

  ads.forEach(function(ad) {
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  });
}

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', parseAds);
```

Comment: Already upvoted, but please can you show a full implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this and see if it will help.

http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/google_adsense.html